# A method not getting called because of a NullRefrence exeption error

Tags: unity

I am getting a nullrefrenceexception error from my main script where I try to run a method from another script and I get that error. I also get this warning: "You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent(). Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all." Also I know that the if statement becomes true bc I put a Debug.Log in and it gave a response

These are my scripts: (I am aware that there is probably some ugly/bad code, I am sorry for that I am new to unity/c#)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;


public class EnemyBaseScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health;
    public float speed;
    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    public float inRange;
    public float inView;    
    public Enemy enemy;
    public GameObject self;
    public bool MultiAttack = false;

    public GameObject playerPos;

    private float SelectedDifficulty;
        
    private Animator anim;

    private bool lookOnce = true;
    
    private Weapon weaponGettingHitBy;
    

    private void Awake()
    {
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {           

        enemy = new Enemy(health, speed, agent, inRange, inView);
        agent = gameObject.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
                
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        Invoke("LookForPlayer", 5.0f);
        if (lookOnce)
        {
            LookForPlayer();
            lookOnce = false;
        }

        if (health < 0)
        {
            health = 0;
            StartCoroutine(JustDies());
        }
       //this part is the part giving the error
        if (PlayerPos.FindPlayerPos(inRange, playerPos, inView, self))
        {
           TimeToFight.ChoseChasingWhatStateToAttackPlayer(agent, playerPos, self, anim, MultiAttack); // this line is where the error/warning are happening
        }
       
    }    
        
    IEnumerator JustDies()
    {
        anim.SetBool("isDead", true);
        //GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("isDead", true);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4.5f);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    public GameObject LookForPlayer()
    {
        playerPos = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        return playerPos;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Weapon")
        {
            weaponGettingHitBy = new Weapon(col.gameObject, col.gameObject.GetComponent<WeaponBaseScript>().damage);
            health = TakeDamage.TakeDmg(health, weaponGettingHitBy);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the script that they are referencing:

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using UnityEngine;


public class TimeToFight : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum State
    {
        Chase,
        Attack,
        Block,
        Idle,
        Wander
    }

    public static State state = State.Idle;
    private static bool rand = true;

    public static void ChoseChasingWhatStateToAttackPlayer(NavMeshAgent agent, GameObject playerPos, GameObject Gself, Animator anim, bool MultiAttack) 
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case State.Chase:
                ChasePlayer(playerPos, Gself, anim, agent);
                break;
            case State.Attack:
                AttackPlayer(playerPos, anim, agent, Gself, MultiAttack);
                break;
            case State.Block:
                BlockPlayer(playerPos, anim, agent);
                break;
            case State.Idle:
                IdlePlayer(playerPos, anim, agent, Gself);
                break;
            case State.Wander:
                WanderPlayer(playerPos, anim, agent);
                break;
        }
    }
    
    public static void ChasePlayer(GameObject playerPos, GameObject self, Animator anim, NavMeshAgent agent)
    {
        agent.SetDestination(playerPos.transform.position);

        distDif = Vector3.Distance(playerPos.transform.position, self.transform.position);
        if (distDif <= 3.5f)
        {
            state = State.Attack;
        }        
    }

    public static void BlockPlayer(GameObject playerPos, Animator anim, NavMeshAgent agent)
    {

    }
//this is the area that I think might give the error however I am not sure
    static MonoBehaviour haha;
    public static void IdlePlayer(GameObject playerPos, Animator anim, NavMeshAgent agent, GameObject self)
    {
        
        if (rand)
        {
            rand = false;
            haha = new MonoBehaviour();
            LookAroundArea(self);
            haha.StartCoroutine(RandomlyWander());
            
        }
    }
   
    
    static IEnumerator RandomlyWander()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        if (10 >= Random.Range(1, 1000))
        {
            state = State.Wander;
        }
        rand = true;
    }

    static IEnumerator LookAroundArea(GameObject self)
    {
        self.transform.Rotate(0.0f, 10, 0.0f, Space.Self);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);        
        self.transform.Rotate(0.0f, -20, 0.0f, Space.Self);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        self.transform.Rotate(0.0f, 10, 0.0f, Space.Self);
    }
}

```
````

Comment: Hi! This is a bit too much code for volunteers to comb through. Please narrow down your problem to a smaller bit of code. Also the error should tell you which line is causing the problem, so you could also tell us that.

Comment: Okay I will do that

Comment: It looks to me like your errors are telling you quite clearly what's wrong here. I've linked this question to existing Q&A we have, explaining how null reference exceptions can arise from incorrect code in Unity and how to avoid them. When editing your question to focus on a single issue, be sure to show how you've tried applying existing resources like this to solving your problem, and where you're running into trouble with the solutions you've found in your research so far.